# I was trying to build a unique() function from scratch, but looks like the for loop isn't iterating after the first loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I was trying to build a unique() function from scratch, but looks like the for loop isn't iterating after the first loop

```
def uni(x):
    s = set(l)
    count = 0
    for i in s:
        for j in x:
            if i == j:
                count += 1
        return f"{i}: {count}"



l = ["business", "business", "business", "economy", "economy", "economy", "economy", "business", "premium", "business", "first"]
xx = uni(l)
print(xx)
```

i want the output to be like
business:5
economy:4
first:1
premium:1

Comment: `return` keyword aborts the execution of the function. Since you put it at the end of the outer loop, only one outer loop's iteration can happen

Comment: Notwithstanding the correct answer from @AlexeyS.Larionov you should probably take a look at the Counter class from the *collections* module

Answer (score 0):

You placed the return statement inside the for loop, which is why it is exiting  after the first iteration

```
    def uni(x):
        s = set(l)
        count = {}
        for i in s:
            for j in x:
                if i == j:
                    count += 1
        return f"{i}: {count}"

l = ["business", "business", "business", "economy", "economy", "economy", "economy", "business", "premium", "business", "first"]
xx = uni(l)
print(xx)
```

try this, hope this helps

Comment: There are numerous errors in this proposed answer which will not run. Did you actually try running the code (always a good idea before submitted to SO). You can't increment `count` which is a Dictionary like that ... and other errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things to point. So, minimally modified version would be like this:

```
def uni(str_array):
    s = set(str_array)
    result = ""
    for i in s:
        count = 0
        for j in str_array:
            if i == j:
                count += 1
        result = result + i + ':' + str(count) + ' '
    return result
```

Or, if you may use `dict`, like this:

```
def uni(str_array):
    s = set(str_array)
    result = {}
    for i in s:
        count = 0
        for j in str_array:
            if i == j:
                count += 1
        result[i] = count
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to build this from scratch (rather than using the Counter class from the *collections* module) then:

```
L = ["business", "business", "business", "economy", "economy", "economy", "economy", "business", "premium", "business", "first"]

def unique(lst):
    d = {}
    for e in lst:
        d[e] = d.get(e, 0) + 1
    return [f'{k}:{v}' for k, v in d.items()]

print(*unique(L))
```

**Output:**

```
business:5 economy:4 premium:1 first:1
```